# sfdx-project.json for second generation package proper ancestry structure?

Tags: second-generation-packaging

Currently my sfdx-project.json looks like this:

```
{
    "packageDirectories": [
        {
            "path": "force-app",
            "package": "my package",
            "versionName": "ver 0.2.4.1",
            "versionNumber": "0.2.4.NEXT",
            "ancestorId": "0.2.3.1 id"
        }
    ],
    "namespace": "my_namespace",
    "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
    "sourceApiVersion": "48.0",
    "packageAliases": {
        "my package": "main-package-id",
        "my package@0.1.0.4": "0.1.0.4 id",
        "my package@0.2.0.1": "0.2.0.1 id",
        "my package@0.2.1.1": "0.2.1.1 id",
        "my package@0.2.2.1": "0.2.2.1 id",
        "my package@0.2.3.1": "0.2.3.1 id"
    }
}
```

So far this is how I gathered how to do this from various searchings online, but haven't found a real clear cut guide on setting up ancestry. The packages in packageAliases are my 'path' of released packages. Am I supposed to keep adding the next version onto my packageAliase list every time I make an update and package? Or do I just need the latest ancestor?

Comment: In my experience you don't actually need to keep any of these earlier versions' details in the sfdx-project.json's package aliases list since these details are available through the CLI using ```sfdx force:package:version:list```. Having this in the JSON file is purely a convenience.

Comment: So building the ancestry list in packageAliases isn't doing anything at all other than kind of keeping a running list for my viewing pleasure?

Comment: Yes, that's my experience and take on it. Worth noting, too, that this has no actual relation to the ancestry, which is purely handled via that ancestor ID.

Comment: BTW have you looked at [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_config_upgrades.htm) around ancestry?

Comment: Yeah I found that document, but was having issues actually packaging with ancestry. Then I finally found some blog that had an sfdx-project.json file set up like mine above, so I tried that and it worked, then I just assumed I had to keep adding to my aliases. And never found concrete documentation explaining this file and the packageAliases part, so I just went with it haha.